# accessing a Form component from another object throws "System.NullReferenceException was unhandled"

Tags: c#

I am trying to modify a TextBox that belongs to Form2 from within a WCF object.

```
namespace server2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private ServiceHost duplex;

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     /// once the form loads, create and open a new ServiceEndpoint.
        {
            duplex = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServerClass));
            duplex.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IfaceClient2Server), new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:9080/service");
            duplex.Open();
            this.Text = "SERVER *on-line*";
        }
    }


    class ServerClass : IfaceClient2Server
    {


        IfaceServer2Client callback;

        public ServerClass()
        {
            callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IfaceServer2Client>();

        }

        public void StartConnection(string name)
        {
            var myForm = Form.ActiveForm as Form2;
            myForm.textBox1.Text = "Hello world!";  /// <- this one trows “System.NullReferenceException was unhandled”
                                                    /// unless Form2 is selected when this fires.

            callback.Message_Server2Client("Welcome, " + name );
        }


        public void Message_Cleint2Server(string msg)
        {
        }

        public void Message2Client(string msg)
        {
        }

    }




    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "server", CallbackContract = typeof(IfaceServer2Client), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]


    public interface IfaceClient2Server           ///// what comes from the client to the server.
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void StartConnection(string clientName);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Message_Cleint2Server(string msg);
    }


    public interface IfaceServer2Client          ///// what goes from the sertver, to the client.
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void AcceptConnection();

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void RejectConnection();

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Message_Server2Client(string msg);
    }

}
```

Yet the "myForm.textBox1.Text = "Hello world!";" line throws System.NullReferenceException was unhandled"...

Any ideas, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the active form is actually an instance of `Form2`? If not, then `as` will return `null`.

Comment: no, actually its not! how should I access it them?

Comment: We'll need a lot more information about how your forms are setup in order to find out exactly where your instance of "Form2" lives...

Comment: If it isn't a Form2 instance, why are you accessing it? Clearly you're expecting it to be a Form2 instance with that particular textbox on it. You need to tell us, in english, what you want done.

Comment: textBox1 is a Form2 instance. yet I am not accessing it from another from, rather a wcf object.

Comment: This now becomes a WCF question, possibly with threading.  Try to boil down a full example of what you're doing, why, from where.  We don't know anything about your solution that you don't explicitly tell us.  Would your question make sense to you if you didn't know the details?  Try approaching it again, but this time in plain, non-technical English, as Lasse is asking.

Comment: What do you want to happen when Form2 is NOT the ActiveForm?  @Lasse already explained what happens when you attempt an invalid cast, which explains your null condition.  How does this differ from expected/desired behavior?

Comment: Well I want this to always happen with Form2, no matter weather it is active or not.

Comment: What happens if you have more than one instance of Form2 in memory?

Comment: let's assume I have only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments of the initial question, the problem is you're referring to ActiveForm, when the form you want is not active.  Whenever attempting to cast using the `as` keyword, the result will be null if the cast is invalid.  Since you grabbed a form that could not be cast to Form2 (because it was a different kind of form), you correctly received a null reference exception.

Assuming you have enforced singleton rules on Form2 and you haven't played with the form's name, you can access it by way of the [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) collection like so:

```
(Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
```

In your code sample that could look like this:

```
public void StartConnection(string name)
{
    //var myForm = Form.ActiveForm as Form2;
    var myForm = Application.OpenForms["Form2"] as Form2;
    myForm.textBox1.Text = "Hello world!";  /// <- this one trows “System.NullReferenceException was unhandled”
                                            /// unless Form2 is selected when this fires.

    callback.Message_Server2Client("Welcome, " + name );
}
```

That said, I don't think I'd give responsibility of modifying form controls to a WCF service.  I'd much sooner consume events fired by the service inside my form.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Don't forget to consider my last sentence.  ;o)

Answer (score 2):

`myForm` might not be of the `Form2` type, or it might not contain a `textBox1` field.  Make sure to check for null for both those cases.